# Changing relative URLs of Javascript files

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, relative-path

I'm screen scraping using Curl like this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.bbc.com/news/";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

And then I echo the content on an HTML page. The problem is that when I look in my console I see 404 errors because of relative URLs assigned to javascript files. For instance if the URL is: `somejavascriptfile.js` on loading the page my domain name is added like so: `http://mydomain/somejavascriptfile.js` These paths are obviously not correct.

So what can I do to get the actual URL of the js file instead? If the URLs where in the body I could use jQuery (split/replace) to alter but this wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/base) tag to the scraped HTML.

Open it with an HTML parser like [tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php), go to the start of the head section and append a `<base>` tag. A base tag will redirect all resource access to a known location .

Comment: Isn't the base tag just for redirecting urls instead of changing them? Or is that what tidy does?

Comment: Yes, the tag is for redirecting URLs instead of changing them, that way you won't need to move them to your server for the proxying (assuming that's ok with the web-page you're scraping). Your current code doesn't scrape the JavaScript files (or images, etc) from the web-page anyway.

Comment: I'm talking about js files in the head of document, not about links in the body of document which the base tag is referring to. I'm not getting it...(sorry) Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This will cause all the HTML tags (like script!) to load from the given base address instead of http://mydomain/ (for example http://theirdomain/ )

Comment: Thank you:) I tried this `$('head').prepend('<base href="http://www.bbc.com/news/">');` It works but I'm still getting 404 errors. I think it is because I echo the document in Iframe and doing my event on Iframe load, so I might be to 'late' with my event(prepend). Anyway, is using tidy required in this case or did you just mentioned it as good advice?

Comment: Tidy would have been used if you wanted this done on the server-side (to avoid those 404 errors). If it works this way with jQuery, there is no problem with continuing doing that. Glad I could help