# Changing path to folder on server

Tags: php, jquery, path, timthumb, waterfall

Is it possible to change this script to direct it's path to a folder?

```
<script>
   $('#container').waterfall({
   itemCls: 'item',
   colWidth: 222,  
   gutterWidth: 15,
   gutterHeight: 15,
   checkImagesLoaded: false,
   path: function(page) {
       return 'data/data1.json?page=' + page;
    }
});
</script>
```

I already have a PHP script works in finding the server folder.

```
   <?php
    $dirname = "photos/home/";
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    shuffle($images);
    $ignore = Array(".", "..");
    foreach($images as $curimg){
        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
            echo "<img src='img.php?src=".$dirname.$curimg."  ' />\n";
        }
    }                 
   ?>
```

**Is it possible to combine both scripts together either in PHP our jquery, or both?**

Thank you.

Erik

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing relative URLs of Javascript files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849084/changing-relative-urls-of-javascript-files)